# Query to determine the id of the student who has the highest average in Physics, Chemistry and Mathematics

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table named `marks` with two columns `student_id` and `marks`.
`student_id` column contains a unique id of the student
`marks` column contains marks of the five different subject of the student Separated by comma. I tried multiple ways to determine the id of the student who has the highest average in Physics, Chemistry, and Mathematics. I am not able to get my output. Can someone please help here?
Data looks like below:
Table - `marks`

```
Student Id | marks
101        | 93,63,74,29,57
102        | 63,66,34,89,27
103        | 93,64,54,22,97
104        | 43,93,34,78,87
105        | 95,83,54,49,78
```

This can be interpreted as first-row student id 101.His/Her Physics marks - 93, Chemistry mark - 63, maths mark - 74, history - 29, philosophy - 57
Below my query that I tried. First, I split the marks column into multiple columns. But I am not able to determine the id of the student who has the highest average in Physics, Chemistry, and Mathematics. I am not able to get my output.
Expected Output:
Highest mark in physics student id - 105
Highest mark in chemistry student id - 104
Highest mark in mathematics student id - 101

Output should display only the studentid who is having the highest average of first three subject

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
SELECT student_id,SPLIT_STR(marks, ',', 1) as physics,
     SPLIT_STR(marks, ',', 2) as chemistry,
     SPLIT_STR(marks, ',', 3) as mathematics,
      SPLIT_STR(marks, ',', 4) as history ,
      SPLIT_STR(marks, ',', 5) as philosophy 
FROM   marks;
```

Comment: update your question and show the expected  result

Comment: The "real" answer here is use that function to normalize your data.Put marks into a separate row.

Comment: select student_id
from marks
order by substring(marks, 1, 2) + substring(marks, 4, 2) + substring(marks, 7, 2) desc
limit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this below option-

```
SELECT D.*,E.`Student Id` FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT Subject,MAX(Marks) Max_Marks FROM
        (
            SELECT `Student Id`, 'physics' Subject,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(marks, ',', 1) Marks
            FROM your_table A

            UNION ALL

            SELECT `Student Id`, 'chemistry' Subject,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(marks,concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(marks, ',', 1),','),''), ',', 1) Marks
            FROM your_table A

            UNION ALL

            SELECT `Student Id`, 'mathematics' Subject,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(marks,concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(marks, ',', 2),','),''), ',', 1) Marks
            FROM your_table A
        )B
        GROUP BY Subject
    )C
) D
INNER JOIN 

(
    SELECT `Student Id`, 'physics' Subject,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(marks, ',', 1) Marks
    FROM your_table A

    UNION ALL

    SELECT `Student Id`, 'chemistry' Subject,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(marks,concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(marks, ',', 1),','),''), ',', 1) Marks
    FROM your_table A

    UNION ALL

    SELECT `Student Id`, 'mathematics' Subject,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(marks,concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(marks, ',', 2),','),''), ',', 1) Marks
    FROM your_table A
)E ON D.Subject = E.Subject AND D.Max_Marks = E.Marks;
```

Output is-

```
chemistry   93  104
mathematics 74  101
physics     95  105
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion ... If the same arguments mark are ever in the same position
  you could obatin the normalized  values for the arguments  using a subquery

```
   select studentId
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(marks,',',1),",",-1) physics
    ,  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(marks,',',2),",",-1) chemistry
    ,  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(marks,',',3),",",-1) mathematics
    ,  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(marks,',',4),",",-1) history
    ,  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(marks,',',5),",",-1) philosophy
  from marks
```

and use this subquery result as table for your further analysis

Comment: Thank you. It is very helpful. But How to determine the id of the student who has the highest average in Physics, Chemistry, and Mathematics? Can you please suggest?